# Dynamically naming DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Imagine I have 2 data frames as such:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
bar = pd.DataFrame({'c':[7,8,9], 'd':[10,11,12]})
```

I want to subset each of these data frames and put them in a new data frame with a dynamic name. When I look up anything on dynamic naming in python, they say, don't do it, use a [dictionary](https://www.google.com/#q=dynamic+naming+python). 
I can't quite figure out how to make it work though. Essentially I want the following:

```
foo_first = foo[0:1]
bar_first = bar[0:1]
```

But I want to be able to do it looping through a list. I would imagine it something like this, if I'm trying to do it with a dictionary:

```
dfs_list = [foo, bar]
dfs_dict = {}

for x in dfs_list:
    dfs_dict[x+'_first']=foo[0:1]
```

Which does not work.

You might be wondering what I'm actually trying to do, as my example is so arbitrary and pointless. In my real world example, I have several data frames indexed by date. I want to create new dataframes based on the names of these old dataframes for the current year and month. So if foo and bar were giant datasets with date indexes, I want to automate:

```
foo_year = foo['2015-01-01':'2015-12-31']
bar_year = bar['2015-01-01':'2015-12-31']
foo_month = foo['2015-08-01':'2015-08-31']
bar_month = foo['2015-08-01':'2015-08-31']
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any reason you couldn't use a dictionary of `DataFrame`s. This will let you avoid needing to treat the variable names as data:

```
whole_dataframes = {"foo": foo, "bar": bar}
first_dataframes = {name: value[:1] for name, value in whole_dataframes.items()}
```

I'm using the `foo` and `bar` variables you've described to initialize the first dict, but you can probably skip that step and just create the values directly in the dict:

```
whole_dataframes = {}
whole_dataframes["foo"] = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
whole_dataframes["bar"] = pd.DataFrame({'c':[7,8,9], 'd':[10,11,12]})
```