# Pandas display Dataframe outside of loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new in Python, trying to figure out Dataframe in pandas. I am filtering my Dataframe and divide it into many Dataframe according to filter. But after filtering can't display dataframe outside of loop.

```
i = 0 
while i < len(someArray):
    container = 'df' + str(i)
    container = df[(df['column'] == someArray[i][0])]
    container = pd.DataFrame(container)
    #print(container.head())
    i = i + 1
df0.head()
```

When I try to display Dataframe suppose `df0.head()` outside of loop, error message showing `df0` is not defined. But inside of loop showing the result.

Comment: `container` value is changing. So not possible to define `df0`

Comment: What do you think this does? `container = 'df' + str(i)`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859101/how-to-generate-dynamic-variable-names-in-pandas-dataframe#34859178

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577939/dynamically-naming-dataframes-in-pandas

Comment: The duplicates basically suggest using a dictionary. Something like `d[i] = container`, and then your last line would be `d[0].head()`.